# Add an anonymous subclass object to a base class list

Tags: c#, list, reflection, polymorphism

I have a base class (Baseclass) from which I derived some subclasses (Subclass1, Subclass2, etc.).
For each subclass, I want:

- call the constructor with 'fixed' arguments (arg1, arg2, etc.);
- check if the instantiation is valid (supposing to have a common method IsValid); and
- add the instantiation to a list of object.

Here follows the excerpt of the code:

```
subclassList = new List<Type>()
{
   typeof(Subclass1),
   typeof(Subclass1),
   ...
};
List<Baseclass> objectList = new List<Baseclass>();
foreach (Type subclass in subclassList)
{
   ConstructorInfo[] constructorArray = subclass.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public);
   object o = constructorArray[0].Invoke(new object[] { arg1, arg2, ... });
   if (((Baseclass)o).IsValid)
   {
      objectList.Add(Convert.ChangeType(o, subclass));
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add an item of type `object` into your objectList. You should cast the converted item to `Baseclass` for the `Add` method to accept to pass the compilation:

```
                var conv = Convert.ChangeType(o, subclass);
                objectList.Add((Baseclass)conv);
```

Comment: I want to loop on a set of subclasses and do some operation for each subclass. The compiler doesn't 'like' the Add line, because it doesn't recognize o as an instantiation of a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ChangeType` is not really needed in this case, you would just need one cast. Also, if you need to invoke a constructor, you can use the `Activator` class, which is more convenient for this case than using reflection.

Here is a complete working example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

// some fake classes just so I can compile the example
class Baseclass {
    public bool IsValid {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
class Subclass1 : Baseclass {
}
class Subclass2 : Baseclass {
}

class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var subclassList = new List<Type>() {
           typeof(Subclass1),
           typeof(Subclass1)
        };
        List<Baseclass> objectList = new List<Baseclass>();
        foreach (Type subclass in subclassList) {
            Baseclass newObject = (Baseclass)Activator.CreateInstance(subclass);
            if (newObject.IsValid) {
                objectList.Add(newObject);
            }
        }

    }
}
```